# Tempmute command in discord.py its not removing the muterole

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(description="Mutes the specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400}
    mute_time = int(time[0]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
    mute = discord.Embed(
        description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> {member.mention} was muted.\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
        color=ctx.author.color)
    mute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    muteprvt = discord.Embed(
        description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> You have muted from {ctx.guild.name}\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
        color=ctx.author.color)
    muteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
    await ctx.member.send(embed=muteprvt)
    await asyncio_sleep(mute_time)
    await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
    unmute = discord.Embed(description=f" {member.mention} was unmuted.", color=ctx.author.color)
    unmute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=unmute)
    unmuteprvt = discord.Embed(description=f" You have unmuted from {ctx.guild.name}", color=ctx.author.color)
    unmuteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await member.send(embed=unmuteprvt)
    return

    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted by ez")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
    mute = discord.Embed(
        description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> {member.mention} was muted.\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
        color=ctx.author.color)
    mute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    muteprvt = discord.Embed(
        description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> You have muted from {ctx.guild.name}\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
        color=ctx.author.color)
    muteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
    await ctx.member.send(embed=muteprvt)
    await asyncio_sleep(mute_time)
    await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
    unmute = discord.Embed(description=f" {member.mention} was unmuted.", color=ctx.author.color)
    unmute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=unmute)
    unmuteprvt = discord.Embed(description=f" You have unmuted from {ctx.guild.name}", color=ctx.author.color)
    unmuteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await member.send(embed=unmuteprvt)
    return
```

thats my code the problem is its not removing the role can someone help me?
i have the time converted and stuff so its all perfectly working but idk maybe the asyncio module is not working bcs there is also nothing in auditlog

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: Try to use `print` statements to see where the bot get stuck. This is a lot of code and hard to follow where the error could be.

Comment: how to use it im new and never used print command

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
@client.command(description="Mutes the specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400}
    mute_time = int(time[:-1]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]
    print(mute_time)
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted by ez")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True,
                                          read_messages=False)
        await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
        mute = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564>   {member.mention} was muted.\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
            color=ctx.author.color)
        mute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
        mutep = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564>   You have muted from {ctx.guild.name}\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
            color=ctx.author.color)
        mutep.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await member.send(embed=mutep)
        await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
        await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
        unmute = discord.Embed(description=f" {member.mention} was unmuted.", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=unmute)
        unmuteprvt = discord.Embed(description=f" You have unmuted from {ctx.guild.name}", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmuteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await member.send(embed=unmuteprvt)
    else:
        await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
        mute = discord.Embed(description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564>   {member.mention} was muted.\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}", color=ctx.author.color)
        mute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
        mutep = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564>   You have muted from {ctx.guild.name}\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
            color=ctx.author.color)
        mutep.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await member.send(embed=mutep)
        await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
        await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
        unmute = discord.Embed(description=f" {member.mention} was unmuted.", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=unmute)
        unmuteprvt = discord.Embed(description=f" You have unmuted from {ctx.guild.name}", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmuteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await member.send(embed=unmuteprvt)
```

got it fixed it was actually only the embed wich was wrong lol.
so whoever wants to use it u can have it
and thank u for ur help Dominik!

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to all sorts of things here.

You don't use `asyncio` the way you have it written there. Try `asyncio.sleep(mute_time)`  instead, because `asyncio_sleep` does not exist.

Also, you should know that the code that follows `return` cannot be reached, because everything after that is blocked as seen in my screenshot. How the code should still work for you is questionable.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Code not reachable]

Also, you should check earlier if the `mutedRole` is present, otherwise you will get an `AttributeError` error. So simply put your `if not mutedRole:` statement somewhere **before** you are trying to add the role.

Comment: just watch my edit ahead

Comment: i think its my time convert

Comment: It has to be `mute_time = int(time[:-1]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]` and `asyncio.sleep(mute_time)`

Comment: ye i tried that now this is also not working :|
i added ur features....

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
@client.command(description="Mutes the specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400}
    mute_time = int(time[:-1]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]
    print(mute_time)
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted by ez")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
        await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
        mute = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> {member.mention} was muted.\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
            color=ctx.author.color)
        mute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        muteprvt = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> You have muted from {ctx.guild.name}\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
            color=ctx.author.color)
        muteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
        await ctx.member.send(embed=muteprvt)
        await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
        await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
        unmute = discord.Embed(description=f" {member.mention} was unmuted.", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=unmute)
        unmuteprvt = discord.Embed(description=f" You have unmuted from {ctx.guild.name}", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmuteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await member.send(embed=unmuteprvt)
    else:
        await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
        mute = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> {member.mention} was muted.\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
            color=ctx.author.color)
        mute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        muteprvt = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<a:mutediscord:888827254853996564> You have muted from {ctx.guild.name}\n**Reason:** {reason}\n**Duration** {time}",
            color=ctx.author.color)
        muteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
        await ctx.member.send(embed=muteprvt)
        await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
        await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
        unmute = discord.Embed(description=f" {member.mention} was unmuted.", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmute.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=unmute)
        unmuteprvt = discord.Embed(description=f" You have unmuted from {ctx.guild.name}", color=ctx.author.color)
        unmuteprvt.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await member.send(embed=unmuteprvt)
```

added all ur features